# Error al importar matplotlib en python

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver estoy utilizando Anaconda, y en ese entorno python v. 3.6.6.
Apenas se ejecuta "import matplotlib.pyplot" la aplicacion se "rompe". He buscado en StackOverflow anglosajon, pero nada util. Creo que se trata de problemas de versiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es Anaconda navigator 1.8.7

Comment: ¿estas segura que tienes instalado matplotlib?

Comment: Si. tengo las librerias que necesito

Comment: En anaconda tengo entornos donde instalo las librerias, en este caso "tensorflow" asi se llama el entorno, ya he instalado varias librerias facilmente con anaconda. Y matplotlib esta instalado, en todo caso saldria un error diferente relativo a la inexistencia de "matplotlib"

Comment: mmm, puede ser, pero en estos casos siempre hay que dudar de todo ya que no hay una pista clara del error ni de su causa, por ejemplo crea un archivo .py que solo importe matplolib y lanzalo usanso la cmd: `python archivo.py`.

Comment: Por otro lado: ¿estas seguro que estas usando el python correcto?, parece que tienes virtualenv por lo que probablemente estes usando otro python

Comment: Eso de probar un archivo importando solo la libreria lo llegue a hacer. Y efectivamente, el mismo error. Respecto a la version de python, pues no lo se, es posible que se trate de la version, en el entorno estoy usando python 3.6.6

Comment: Tu señalas que creaste un entorno llamado `tensorflow`, ¿como estas seguro que estas usando ese entorno?

Comment: Bueno, en Anaconda me da una lista de mis entornos. En este caso sobre "tensorflow" le doy click derecho "Abrir terminal". Es asi como es he estado probando mis scripts.

Comment: okay, ya veo, me parece extraño, ¿tienes el mismo problema con otras librerias?

Comment: No realmente, queria trabajar desplegando imagenes y todo eso. Hay algo interesante, sin utilizar Anaconda, empleando solo una terminal comun y el python que tengo instalado ya hace mucho, no aparece el error, se importa matplotlib sin problemas. Esto me dice que el problema es Anaconda y matplotlib. Respecto al problema solo vi stackoverflow en ingles, y no dicen nada concreto

Answer (score 2):

He logrado solucionarlo. Se me ocurrio **actualizar** el matplotlib mediante anaconda a la version 2.2.3.
Luego ejecute el simple comando de "import matplotlib.pyplot", y ya, no aparece ningun error.
Aun me parece extraño que solo por ser version ni tan vieja causara un crash.

Comment: ¿que versión de matplotlib tenias?

Comment: Era la version 2.2.2.

Comment: Era la version entre la 2.2.0 y la 2.2.2. No me he fijado exactamente pero era una version 2.x.x